# Are there any major websites that have stopped supporting IE8? If so, which ones?

Tags: ipad, html, css, internet-explorer-8, mobile-browser

I am creating some new layouts which would work on both desktop (IE,FF,Safari) and mobile browsers (mainly tablets like iPad)

Now the UI designs have a lot of touch-based things, curved borders/gradients, audio/video, etc and would be completely fluid (no fixed px)

To summarize, it seems like using HTML5, CSS3 would be a better approach even from a future perspective. However, IE8 (one of the major browsers) has limited support for HTML5/CSS3 and no media query support. While some of these things have workarounds, I am not really sure whether supporting IE8 would be a good idea.

I wanted to know if there are any major websites which have officially stopped supporting IE8 and if yes, which are they ?

Comment: It depends on the *audience* of users that you're targeting and what browsers they use. Aside from that, this will only result in another argument that is not welcome on SO.

Comment: Even IE9 has pretty limited support for major parts of CSS3 (no transitions or animations).

Comment: Totally agree, that IE8 should not be supported. It was a good browser when it first came out, but it's holding back the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoa, hold your horses, there's still discussions going on about whether IE6 should be supported. IE8 is a definite yes. Don't remove support for it!

As web developers we LOVE to bash on IE versions - it's so fun, with their weird interpretations of browser standards, but you have to realise that removing support is like chopping a portion of your user base out of the mix. Why would you want less visitors?

IE9 hasn't long been out on release so don't drop support for legacy versions unless you have a very good reason.

I know we love CSS3 and HTML5 but for most things there are Javascript workarounds to keep the browser degradation to a minimum.

I would suggest that NO major websites have removed support for IE8.

Comment: In your last sentence, did you mean IE6?

Comment: 6 months is a pretty long time in the web world now, considering they're already working on IE10 too. Heck, Firefox is already on 8 Beta.

Comment: Nah, the original question asked which major websites have removed support for IE8, and my last sentence was answering that.

Comment: Not sure what planet you're still on. Microsoft stopped supporting IE6 in September. See: http://www.ie6countdown.com/ Note: This is a Microsoft website.

Comment: Firefox increments major version numbers like other projects increment their minor version or bug fix numbers. It seems like a marketing move, just like when proprietary software uses year numbers instead of version numbers.

Comment: @jer :S I read an outdated article. Some people still use it - government and councils for one, other large organisations refuse to upgrade. But this discussion is about IE8 not IE6

Answer (score 1):

Every browser has limited support for HTML5/CSS3. Here's [one table](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) of compatibilities.

The real question is, what is your audience? In my case, I designed an intranet site and decided to drop all support for IE. If IE worked, swell! If it didn't, then it cost less for the user to install Firefox or Chrome just for my app than for me to write my site twice, which is pretty much what IE 6 support will push you into.

I thought IE 8 was one of the good ones, though? Certainly it was supposed to be more secure and easier to support than IE 6.

Comment: I 100% agree with your last sentiment. For intranets where YOU have control over what browser people use (in essence) then only supporting a single browser is fine. If your website is public then it'd be best to support it all just in case.

Comment: I mentioned it because old intranet apps that are designed around IE 6 (and fail with later versions) are one of the reasons IE 6 is still around. The companies that use these apps don't want to spend money upgrading, and will only do so if their IE 6 requirement starts hurting them elsewhere. But again, the OP says nothing of their audience, which is the most important consideration.